# releasing views in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [calling [myString release] does NOT decrement [myString retainCount]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213647/calling-mystring-release-does-not-decrement-mystring-retaincount)

I am in very big problem please help me to solve the same.

I am creating a view in custom way as

```
   UIView *view = [self getCustomVIew:index];
   [view release];
   view = nil;
```

In `getCustomVIew:index`, I am allocating and returning the view. When I release view as

```
   [view release];
```

it is not releasing the view from `getCustomView:index` and the reference count is not decremented.

Please help me to release the view returned from `getCustomVIew:index` and to maintain the memory size.

Instruments is just increasing the overall size of program when the views get deleted.

Comment: How do you know it is not being decremented?, the message to count is often not accurate. Also since getCustomView is returning an owned object rename the metho dname to newCustomView.

Comment: Do not prefix methods with **get**.  That has a special meaning in Cocoa and this isn't it.  **retainCount** is useless.  Don't call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to release view from that `getCustomVIew` method. Returned view from should be already marked as `autorelease`

```
-(UIView*) customView{
    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] init];
    ...
    return [v autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Edited to reflect that no method in iOS or Cocoa should ever be prefixed with `get*` unless it returns a value by reference, which this one does not do...

Answer (score 0):

You need not to release that `view` in  `getCustomVIew:`. Instead send `autorelease` signal before returning. After you get that `view` object also, you need not to release since it is already autoreleased.

Answer (score 0):

your code seems fine and if you are trying to use "view.reatinCount" to ensure that view is released, it is not good.

here is the exact duplicate issue you may refer:
[calling [myString release] does NOT decrement [myString retainCount]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213647/calling-mystring-release-does-not-decrement-mystring-retaincount)