# If I set MPMovieControlStyleNone to the property controlStyle at the MPMoviePlayerController, Why is the reference count goes up 2?

Tags: iphone

If I set MPMovieControlStyleNone to the property controlStyle at the MPMoviePlayerController,
Why is the reference count goes up 2?
In addition,  How can I release _player object ?

I made a Class that inherits from UIViewController.

Instance variable

```
NSString* _movieFilename;
MPMoviePlayerController* _player;
```

Implementation

```
- (MPMoviePlayerController*)makeMoviePlayer:(NSString*)res {
    NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:res ofType:@""]];
    MPMoviePlayerController* player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    if (url == nil) return nil;
    player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    return player;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    _player=[self makeMoviePlayer:_movieFilename];

    if(_player == nil) return;

    NSLog(@"[_player retainCount]=%d", [_player retainCount]);

}
```

Implementation 1
  The implementation as described above.
Implementation 2
  Delete the fifth row of the implementation.
  player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;

Result 1

```
[_player retainCount]=3
```

Result 2

```
[_player retainCount]=1
```

In implementation 2 _payer object can be released in [_player release] .
In implementation 1, retainCount is 3.
After the execution of  [_player release] , retainCount is 2.
_player object will not be released. 
Why retainCount increase 2 ?
How can I release _player object ?

Comment: The right answer is [Do not relay on retaincount](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3213750/991816). Recommend you to delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

retainCount is useless.  Don't call it.

To answer your specific question, you fix the issue by following the [memory management rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html).

First, your `makeMoviePlayer:` method should return an autoreleased object and your viewDidLoad should retain it.   It should be released when you no longer need it.

Better yet, turn on ARC.